# Doctest on function with random.random module

Tags: python-3.x, doctest

How would a doctest on a function with random.random module look like. What i mean is, if the method generates a list with 360 different random numbers between 0-1 how could you test it?

```
def berakna_slump_tal(self):
    self.slump_tal = []   
    t = 0                
    while t <= 360:
        slump = random.random()
        self.slump_tal.append(slump) 
        t = t + 1
```

Is it posible to test this with doctest in a seperat file.

This is how i run the doctest.

```
python -m doctest solNy.doctest
```

Answer (score 0):

You can test that the result list's values all hold the condition of being between 0 and 1:

```
>>> res = berakna_slump_tal()
>>> all([0 <= val <= 1 for val in res])
True
```